# Serverless function crashes with Runtime exited error: exit status 1 on Vercel deployment

Tags: node.js, express, vercel, ably-realtime

I am making a website using whatsapp-web.js package in node.js. Everything is working fine in localhost. Here I have used ably (Realtime server) But when I want to deploy website on vercel, it is not working.

I get error like  **Serverless function crashes**.
In the runtime logs I get this error -

> …RequestId: 6be3dd2c-512d-4625-87c7-1fe6e978bd99 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
> Runtime.ExitError

Comment: Did you find any solution

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.
Make sure you've created a **vercel.json** file  in the root folder and it contains:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "app.js", // app staring point
      "use": "@now/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "app.js" // app staring point
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Any typescript solution?